# Sort std::vector<std::string *> overloading <

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, operator-overloading, stdvector

- I want to use `std::sort()` on a `std::vector<std::string *>`.
- For this, I want to overload `<`.
- I want to use this operator to compare the first character in the String
- I guess the `std::sort()` function doesn't call my operator because the vector actually has `std::string *` as type instead of `std::string`. But I'm not sure how to specify this.
- I would like to achieve this without using a third parameter in `std::sort()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool operator<(std::string& str_1, std::string& str_2){
    std::cout<<str_1[0] <<" < " << str_2[0] << std::endl;
    return str_1[0] < str_2[0];
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string str1 = "abc";
    std::string str2 = "def";
    std::string str3 = "ghi";
    std::string str4 = "bcd";
    std::string str5 = "fgh";

    //test the operator first
    std::cout << (str1<str2) << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::string *> str_vector;
    str_vector.push_back(&str1);
    str_vector.push_back(&str2);
    str_vector.push_back(&str3);
    str_vector.push_back(&str4);
    str_vector.push_back(&str5);

    std::sort(str_vector.begin(), str_vector.end());

    for (std::vector<std::string *>::iterator it=str_vector.begin(); it!=str_vector.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << **it << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The operator seems to be well implemented, but is never called during `std::sort()`
This is the console output:

```
a < d
1
 fgh
 bcd
 ghi
 def
 abc
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

THANKS!

Comment: What is the type sort is trying to compare? What is the type handled by your operator? If they don't match, then overload resolution will not select your operator.

Comment: Why do you have vector of pointers in the first place?

Comment: true, I'll write it  in the question, I just want to compare the first character of the string

Comment: @Yksisarvinen , the vector reates a copy of the elements. Later, I want to achieve this with more complicated classes. So I wanted something light in memory :) ... Am I wrong on somethig?

Comment: Your conditions are impossible, you're going to have to compromise on one of them.

Comment: Are we talking about millions of objects here? If not, impact on memory will be hardly noticeable, and with your approach you get a ton of cache misses due to dereferencing memory in potentially different areas (worst offender against execution time). Read about *move semantics* in your favourite textbook if you are really concerned with extra copies.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks! I'll check that out :) ... the objects are actually images, which contain millions of uint16_t s... And the first pixels have metadata that will allow me to sort them

Comment: @Ivan I see. In this case you should really get on good terms with `std::move` (and worries about cache misses become less important)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I'll check that out too then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a vector of pointers to objects of the type `std::string`

```
std::vector<std::string *> str_vector;
```

So if you will call the standard algorithm `std::sort` without specifying the comparison function then the algorithm will try to sort the vector comparing the pointers themselves without comparing the pointed objects.

But if you would declare a vector of objects of `std::string` instead of pointers nevertheless your overloaded `operator <` will not be found because the definition of the function `std::sort` is in the namespace `std` and in this namespace there will be found the standard overloaded `operator <`.

You could sort the vector of pointers using your own overloaded `operator <` if you will use your own comparison function as for example a lambda expression.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool operator <( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
{
    std::cout << "Bingo\n";

    return s1[0] < s2[0];
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s[] = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "bcd", "fgh" };

    std::vector<std::string *> v1;
    v1.reserve( sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ) );

    std::transform( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ), std::back_inserter( v1 ),
                    []( auto &s ) { return &s; } );

    std::sort( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ), 
               []( const auto &p1, const auto p2 )
               {
                    return *p1 < *p2;
               } );                 

    for ( const auto &p : v1 )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Bingo
Bingo
Bingo
Bingo
Bingo
Bingo
Bingo
Bingo
Bingo
Bingo
Bingo
abc bcd def fgh ghi
```

As you can see due to the test output of the string `"Bingo"` your `operator <` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You have overloaded `operator<` for `string::string`, but `str_vector` contains `std::string *`.

Since you can't change the behaviour for operators on primitive types like pointers, you need to provide a custom comparator as last parameter to `std::sort`. For example as lambda:

```
std::sort(str_vector.begin(), str_vector.end(),
[](const std::string *str_1, const std::string *str_2){
    std::cout << (*str_1)[0] <<" < " << (*str_2)[0] << std::endl;
    return (*str_1)[0] < (*str_2)[0];
});
```